# TYPO3 permissions: Allow backend users to copy content elements but not to edit them (or: how to provide users a library of content elements to copy)

Tags: permissions, typo3

i’d be thankful for some help (maybe i didn’t find the correct terms for a search on the internet?).

Topic: Permissions / Module “Access”

I’m looking for a way to configure permissions in such a way that some backend user are in the same time:

- allowed to see (in the page module) all content elements on a certain page
- not allowed to edit/hide/delete them
- are allowed to copy them into the clipboard

The idea is to give them a kind of library pre-filled+preconfigured content elements to copy and paste on “their” pages.

As soon as i disable the permission to “edit content” on the page in the module “access”, they don’t have a “copy” item in the context menu of the content element anymore.
Is there a way to achieve the goal?

Comment: A content repository and the idea of copying the content are contradicting one another. A change/correction of the content would not be taken into account in the copy. So, why not referencing the content? TYPO3 has therefore the content element "(Insert records)[https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/7.6/ContentElements/Shortcut/Index.html]". This way, your editors do not need edit-privileges on the content storage but can insert these content elements.

Comment: It all depends on the use case. I'm not speaking of a "content" repository with centralized content that should synchronize in all its references. Here we need a repository of "preconfigured" content elements, so that the user can copy them, be happy that the preconfigured settings / configuration of the CE mostly fit to their needs and then add content it in.
We also use insert records for other cases, where we need exactly what you pointed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scenario is definitely possible. I've just set up a demo TYPO3 installation where this works fine.

You need to create two backend user groups for access:

- one for the read only page
- and one for the regular pages

In the access module you assign the read only group and set the access rights for read only page only to "Show page".

[image: TYPO3 access module]

Then it should be possible to just copy from that page:

[image: content element with only copy access]

I hope this is helpful for you to reproduce it in your installation.

Comment: Hello Peter,
thanks for your answer.
Actually i did the same but in the "copy" entry wasn't there as soon as i set the access permissions to not being allowed "Edit Content".
In order to reproduce it and tried it again and now the "copy" entry is there in the menu. I really can't figure out what i did differently this time.
So thanks, yes to works: forbidding "Edit Content" doesn't forbid to copy...

Answer (score 1):

Allow your editor to use the content element «Insert Records». So you can place the prefilled and pre-configured content elements on a page without edit permission.
Editor can «clone» the content elements on their page without the possibility to edit them.

[image]

In frontend there is no difference between the original content element and the «clone».

Comment: Thank you Heinz for your answer. What i want is that the user can copy the elements and then edit the copies as they like, so this isn't a solution for me.